# How can I connect an SAS drive to a server mobo without native SAS port

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, sas

Here is my motherboard https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X9DRD-iF.cfm

I don't see SAS listed which is why it's not reading, or because it isn't using an SAS cable. SATA is read fine.

I have an SAS drive which I want to use in this server without buying a different server.

Which ways can I actually connect and use this SAS drive in this motherboard? Is there a cable to connect the serial port? Or what SAS card can I use within it? If there is some other way, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C602 chipset is entry-level and has no SAS function.
Seems that this MB uses only chipset built-in SATA and there is no SAS controller on this MB.

You cannot connect SAS drive to SATA controller, and there are no such cables.
(It can work only vice-versa - SATA drive will work on SAS controller)

You need a SAS HBA card (or SAS RAID if you want the RAID function).
Usually LSI logic or Megaraid cards work fine. Supermicro also has branded SAS adapters.
HP SmartArray controllers are great (and cheap on ebay), but often they cannot work in non-HP motherboards, so I cannot recommend them for Supermicro.

Comment: Thanks but you did not specifically answer exactly what  type of card and exact card to use to connect an SAS drive to this motherboard.

Comment: I cannot specify card model - I don't even know if you need RAID function.
If RAID is not required - almost any card will work.
if you need RAID, you have options
1) buy non-RAID HBA card and make soft RAID (eg mdadm)
2) buy cheap RAID card without battery
3) buy full RAID card with cache and battery backup.

and again - I have too little information about your requirements.

Comment: RAID not required

Comment: Thanks, basically what I did is built a different server while making SAS a requirement. Now my server has SAS built in.